# Bind Ctrl+C to Copy function for eclipse on mac os x doesn't work

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, eclipse

I'm just moving my coding work from Windows to mac os x. It's really difficult to get used to the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and `command` key behavior at beginning.

Then I tried bind <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to `Copy` function instead of <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in eclipse preferences setting. The setting was saved but took no effort. When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on text and then pasted it, nothing happened.

I also don't want to switch the function of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> because many terminal operation still need the original <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> function.

Does <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> conflict with some system shortcut?

Could anybody tell me how to fix this? Or are there any better approaches?

Comment: My advice is : If you work on a Mac get used to use Command instead of Ctrl. It will save you a lot of pain (and you'll get access to a lot of new keyboard shortcuts)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Thanks for your advice. I'll try. A further question, what should I do if I want a PgUp or PgDn function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are better approaches.  Open:

System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts

Highlight the App Shortcuts on left pane.  You will see a list of apps on the right.  Click the Plus sign and then select Eclipse for the app, type the menu item, type your new keyboard shortcut and you are done:

[image: Here is what you need to do]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a system-wide solution, you can simply remap the keyboard modifier keys, by going to System Preferences, Keyboard, and then "Modifier Keys", as shown in the screenshot below.[image]